# When to use half period and when use full period for fourier series coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition) the formula of `An` and `Bn` coefficients are integrals on the full period of the function. but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/214780/588387) the coefficient of fourier series of sin(x) is calculated by integrating on half of period. I'm totally confused what should i use as boundary of coefficient integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an even or even function, twice the half-period integral equals the full-period integral.  Use the half-period integral whenever the function is defined only on $0$ to $L$, so you have the freedom to extend it to an odd or even function (depending on the application.)